# How to place captions to each figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am facing a problem with inserting figures and their caption , my code is as follows

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \centering
        \caption {example1}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-a}
               \vspace{0.01em}
        \caption {example2}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption {example3}
         \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-c}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what the question actually is! Maybe you are looking for the `\usepackage{caption}` with its `\captionof` commadn?

Comment: `\caption` works inside figure or table (floats in general) environments. But do you need captions in a presentation? Just place the text below of each.

Comment: @percusse how would you do it ? that moves with image exactly

Comment: @percusse I just tried to put the text under each but then the image messed up and some images disappear already

Comment: Which side do you need the captions?

Comment: @percusse  on top of each image , even if it is not caption, I just need to write something there

Comment: After centering write  `some caption <empty line> \includegr... <empty line> Another <Empty line>\include....`. Does that come closer? Your images are pretty big though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few options for you.

**First:**

Use `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
        \caption {example1}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
               \vspace{0.01em}
        \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption {example2}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption {example3}
         \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
         \end{columns}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Second**

Use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        example1\\
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \end{tabular}

      \vspace{0.01em}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        example2  & example3 \\
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
         &
         \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
         \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Third**

Use `\captionof`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{capt-of}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \centering
        {\captionof{figure}{example1}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
        }

      \vspace{0.01em}
      \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionof{figure}{example2}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
         \captionof{figure}{example3}
         \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
         \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: look at above in the question, when I use your solution, my images are messing up, I cannot control their size or set them in right place

Comment: @Nemo Your figures have white spaces in the surrounding. Crop them and then use or reduce the size.

Comment: I liked and accepted your solution :-) thanks man